# Tortoise SVN client lost green checkmarks when moving to new PC

Tags: tortoisesvn

I moved to a new laptop and copied all my source code. (going from win XP to Windows 7).  I installed tortoise SVN on the new laptop.  However, when I go to change a source code file and commit it, I don't see the green checkmarks.  So, the new laptop SVN client doesn't know what my old laptop knows.  Does anyone know how to get the SVN client information from my old laptop so I can continue working as before?  (The only other thing I can figure out is to make completely new repositories and IMPORT, but I don't want to do that...)

Comment: How did you get the source code to your new machine? The proper way would have been to so an SVN Checkout after installing the client...

Comment: The name is "icon overlays" and there're some hints in the [TortoiseSVN FAQ section](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlnotshowing).

Comment: I guess I didn't do it the proper way, I just used XCOPY.

Comment: Darn, I wish I had used the "/h" parameter to xcopy to also copy hidden files!  Now I'll have to figure out how to copy ONLY hidden files, since I've changed stuff since then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVN client contains a hidden folder structure beneath your local copy, and that contains the meta data used to communicate with the repository. I suspect you copied over the "visible" files, but not the hidden ones.

Comment: That works, thanks much!!!  All I needed to do was copy the hidden .svn directory underneath the project directory to my new laptop.  Also, if this happens to anyone, don't forget to create an empty "tmp" directory under .svn or your commmits will fail.  Once I did that, everything is back to working, thanks again!